# Setting User permissions for a dynamic website through a database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

I am trying to create permissions for users that are accessing the site.

This is the database table that the permissions are based off

permissions

[image]

The User_privledge_no is the level of access they can hold

Salesperson:1
Admin:2
Stock Controller:3

I have created a file to check that they are logged in which is called check_login.php

```
<?php
// MySQL Database Connect
require_once("connection.php");
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['logged']){
header("Location: employee_login.html");
exit;
}
?>
```

I then have a site_access.php which sets the user's permission levels

```
 <?php
    require_once("connection.php");
    // the following will check to see if the access level is not 2 OR 3 and redirect them – this will allow users with permissions levels 2 and 3 to access the page
    if($_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 2 || $_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 3) {
    header("Location: employee_login.html");
    exit;
    }
    ?>
```

I think that it is something to do with my site_access.php file but I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

You start on the employee_login.html page

which is just a html form. And then once you login you end up on the modify_dept1.php

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang="en">
<?php
require_once("code/connection.php");
require_once("code/check_login.php");
require_once("code/site_access.php");
?>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="Used Car Sales" content="West Coast Auto"/>
    <title>West Coast Auto</title>
    <link href="css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"> <!-- this links the html to the css file-->
</head>

<body> 
    
<header>
<!---------------------------------------------      UPPER NAV    ---------------------->               
<nav id="upper_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="employee_login.html">Employee Login</a></li>  
        <li><a href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="display_vehicle.php">Display Vehicle</a></li>
  <li><a href="add_cust.html">Add Cust</a></li>
  <li><a href="logout.php">LOGOUT</a></li> 
    </ul>
</nav>

<!---------------------------------------------- LOGO AND ADDRESS------------------------>

<div id="logo">  
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/west_coast_auto_logo.png" alt="West Cosst Auto" title="West Coast Auto"></a>   
</div>
    <div id="logos"> 
</div>
    
<div id="address">
    <h4>West Coast Auto</h4>
    <h4>375 Albany Hwy.</h4>
    <h4>Victoria Park</h4>
    <h4>Perth WA 6100</h4>
    <h4>&#9742; (08) 9415 1234</h4>
    <h4>Email: <a href="mailto:Jarvis_Palmer@westcoastauto.com.au  ">Jarvis Palmer</a></h4>
</div>
    
<!-----------------------------------------------  LOWER NAV  ---------------------------------> 
    
<nav id="lower_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="code/index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="code/about.html">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="code/history.html">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="code/our_values.html">Our Values</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="code/used_vehicles.html">Used Vehicles</a></li>
        <li><a href="code/specials.html">Specials</a></li>
        <li><a href="code/finance.html">Finance</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="code/insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="code/testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="code/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> 
<div id="navline">
</div>    
        
</header> 

<!------------------------------------------ MAIN CONTENT -------------------------------->     

<div class="main_img">
<?php
switch ($_SESSION['permissions']) {
case 1:
echo "<h3>Welcome Salesperson</h3>";
break;
case 2:
echo "<h3>Welcome Site Administrator</h3>";
break;
case 3:
echo "<h3>Welcome Stock Controller</h3>";
break;
}
?>
<p><a href="display_cust.php">View Customers</a></p>
<p><a href="display_staff.php">View Staff</a></p>
<p><a href="display_vehicle.php">View Vehicles</a></p>
<?php
if($_SESSION['permissions'] == 2) {
// Display the following menu items only if the user has permission level 4
echo "<p><a href='update_staff.php'>Update Staff</a></p>";
}
?>
<?php
if($_SESSION['permissions'] == 3) {
// Display the following menu items only if the user has permission level 4
echo "<p><a href='update_vehicle.php'>Update Vehicles</a></p>";
}
?>
</div>    
<!------------------------------------------------   FOOTER --------------------------------------->
    
<footer id="footer"> 

    

<button class="accordion"><h2> SITE MAP </h2></button>

<div id="footer_content"> 

<h4 id="site_map">Site Map</h4>
     
<div id="footer_menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="code/index.html">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="code/employee_login.html">Employee Login</a>
    </li>    
    <li><a href="code/privacy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="code/about.html">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="code/history.html">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="code/our_values.html">Our Values</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="code/specials.html">Specials</a></li>
    <li><a href="code/used_vehicles.html">Used Vehicles</a></li>
    <li><a href="code/finance.html">Finance</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="code/insurance.html">Insurance</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="code/testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li><a href="code/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>       
           
<div> 
  <div id="icons">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/facebook.png" title="Facebook" alt="Facebook" width="50" height="50"></a> 
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/youtube.png" title="You Tube" alt="You Tube" width="50" height="50"></a>
      <a href="https://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter.png" title="Twitter" alt="Twitter" width="50" height="50"></a>
  </div>   
     
</div>

<script>
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
    panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";} 
    }
    }
</script>
</div>
</div>
    <p id="copyright">Copyright &copy; 2017 West Coast Auto</p> 
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

It works until I login as someone with a User_privledge_no of 2 and then I can't update certain content, even though I am a level 2 and not a level one.

The same thing happens when I am logged in as someone with a 3 level permissions.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This line has fancy quotes `if($_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 2 || $_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 3) {`.

Comment: @Enstage is it not meant to have fancy quotes?

Comment: No, normal quotes.

Comment: it still didn't work :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logical issues with the IF statement.

Consider...

```
if($_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 2 || $_SESSION[‘permissions’] <> 3) {
```

This will accept permission levels greater or less than 2 OR greater or less than 3 this would render any access level acceptable!

What you need here is;

```
if($_SESSION[‘permissions’] != 2 && $_SESSION[‘permissions’] != 3) {
```

You comments state if the user level is NOT 2 or 3. This would fix this logic.